# ox-reveal not shown in org-export-dispatch

Tags: org-export

I've installed `ox-reveal` package from MELPA with `package-install ox-reveal` and added in the configuration file the following:

```
(setq org-reveal-root "http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/reveal.js/3.0.0/")
```

However, when I try to export a test presentation with `C-c C-e` I don't see an entry for reveal.

I've tried requiring the package with:

```
(require 'ox-reveal)
(setq org-reveal-root "http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/reveal.js/3.0.0/")
```

But that gives me the following error when Emacs starts:

> error: Required feature ‘ox-reveal’ was not provided

Is there something I'm missing?

PS: I'm using Emacs on Cygwing and here's the package versions

```
org                20161118
ox-reveal          20161027.226
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this.  `(require 'ox-reveal)` is the only thing I need to get prompt.  Just in case, have you tried to restart your Emacs?

Comment: @YasushiShoji, yes I restarted it multiple times. Is there any additional info I can provide to make the issue reproducible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Named-Features.html#index-require) states that

> If loading the file succeeds but does not provide feature, require
>   signals an error, ‘Required feature *feature* was not provided’.

The version "20161027.226", which is the version I also have, seems to work fine.  So my guess is that you might have two or more version of `ox-reveal` in your `load-path`.

What happens if you launch a new Emacs instance and do `M-x load-file` and give `~/.emacs.d/elpa/ox-reveal-20161027.226/ox-reveal.el` at the prompt.  And do `C-c C-e`?  If this works, the one you just loaded and the one `(require 'ox-reveal)` loaded is different.

Not sure how you write `~/` on Cygwin, though.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I ended up removing `(require 'ox-reveal)` and [loading the library before exporting](https://github.com/yjwen/org-reveal/blob/001567cc12d50ba07612edd1718b86a12e8c2547/Readme.org#first-try) as stated in the documentation.